# Java: What is the idiomatic way to extract month and year from Date

Tags: java

Let's say I have an instance of a java.util.Date object.

```
Date date = new Date();
```

What is the idiomatic way to extract the year and the month?  It seems that the methods getMonth and getYear have been deprecated.  What should I use instead?

Comment: Seems like it, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The javadoc explains why they've been deprecated, and tells what you should use instead. Read it.

Comment: Wow, -2, touch crowd.  I did, I just didn't find it immediately explanatory.
`getMonth
@Deprecated
public int getMonth()
Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH).
Returns a number representing the month that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object. The value returned is between 0 and 11, with the value 0 representing January.
Returns:
the month represented by this date.
See Also:
Calendar`  This should be something more like `calendarInstance.get(Calendar.MONTH)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date API in Java really is overcomplicated. You should use

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.setTime(date);
 c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: Thanks Joao, that was exactly the snippet I was missing in the docs.

Comment: Actually, both Date *and* Calendar are overcomplicated. Use Joda-Time or java.time.* in Java 8.

Comment: This as it turns out is sufficient for my needs because I am only manipulating dates previously generated and persisted to a database without timezone data appended.  For all things that need timezone aware or consistent behavior I will surely use joda, or upgrade to java 8.

Answer (score 2):

The java.util.Date & Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

Both the question and other answer ignore the critical issue of time zone. If you neglect to specify a time zone, you will get the JVM's default. That means the results of your code vary when run on different computers or changed JVM settings, probably not what you want.

## Joda-Time

This third-party open-source library, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time), is a popular replacement.

Specify a time zone rather than rely on default.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
java.util.Locale locale = java.util.Locale.FRANCE;

DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
int dayOfMonth = now.getDayOfMonth(); 
int monthOfYear = now.getMonthOfYear();  // 1-based counting, January = 1, unlike java.util.Calendar.
String nowAsString = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "F-" ).withLocale( locale ).print( now );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "dayOfMonth: " + dayOfMonth );
System.out.println( "monthOfYear: " + monthOfYear );
System.out.println( "nowAsString: " + nowAsString );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-02-21T05:51:18.688+01:00
dayOfMonth: 21
monthOfYear: 2
nowAsString: vendredi 21 février 2014
```

## java.time.*

[Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) brings a new [java.time.8 package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) to supplant the old j.u.Date/Calendar classes. This new package is inspired by Joda-Time (but re-architected) and defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );

int dayOfMonth = now.getDayOfMonth();
int monthOfYear = now.getMonthValue();  // 1-based counting, January = 1, unlike java.util.Calendar.
String nowAsString = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( Locale.FRANCE ).format( now );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "dayOfMonth: " + dayOfMonth );
System.out.println( "monthOfYear: " + monthOfYear );
System.out.println( "nowAsString: " + nowAsString );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-02-21T06:05:48.833+01:00[Europe/Paris]
dayOfMonth: 21
monthOfYear: 2
nowAsString: vendredi 21 février 2014
```

Comment: Basil, great answer, thank you for putting that together.  I am familiar with joda time and time zone usage.  I thought I didnt have joda time as part of the third party libs on a project I am working on, but it turns out I do as part of the dependencies to gapi.  Cheers